# Prove that a family of subsets of a probability space is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. We define $\mathcal{N}=\{S\subseteq \Omega\ |\ \exists B\in \mathcal{F}: \ P(B)=0, \ S\subseteq B\}$.

I want to prove that the following family is a $\sigma$-algebra:
$$\hat{\mathcal{F}}=\{A\subseteq \Omega\ |\ \exists S \in \mathcal{F}:\ A\triangle S\in \mathcal{N}\}$$
(where $\triangle$ denotes the symmetric difference between two sets: $A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\ \cup\ (B\setminus A))$

Clearly $\hat{\mathcal{F}}\neq\emptyset$ and, for every $A \in \hat{\mathcal{F}},\ A^c=\Omega\setminus A$ is also an element of $\hat{\mathcal{F}}$. The part of the proof that I'm having trouble with is the fact that, for every countable family $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq \hat{\mathcal{F}}$, the union $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is in $\hat{\mathcal{F}}$. Probably I'm missing something obvious, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: remember that if $P(B_k)=0$ for each $k\in \mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$ then $P(\bigcup_{k\geqslant 1}B_k)\leqslant \sum_{k\geqslant 1}P(B_k)=0$. Now observe that if $A_k\in\hat{\mathcal{F}}$ then there exists some $C_k\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $B_k:=A_k\,\triangle\, C_k\in \mathcal{N}$.

Comment: I managed to put together the missing pieces using your hint and the fact that $(\cup_n A_n)\triangle (\cup_n S_n)\subseteq \cup_n (A_n \triangle S_n)$, thanks!